# An inequality for polynomials

Tags: real-analysis, cv.complex-variables, inequalities, integral-operators

I have been thinking about the validity of the following inequality:
 if $P(z)=\sum_{k=0}^na_kz^k, a_n\neq 0$ and $P(z)$ is non-zero in $|z|<1, $ then for  $\theta \in [0, 2\pi],$  and $p>0$
\begin{align*}
  &\int_{0}^{2\pi}\left|n\left(1-\frac{|a_0|-|a_n|}{n(|a_0|+|a_n|)}\right)P(e^{i\theta})+(\eta-e^{i\theta})P'(e^{i\theta})\right|^{p}d\theta\\
  &\qquad\qquad\quad \leq \left[n\left(1-\frac{|a_0|-|a_n|}{n(|a_0|+|a_n|)}\right)\right]^{p}\int_{0}^{2\pi}|P(e^{i\theta})|^{p}d\theta,
  \end{align*}
for any $\eta$ lying in the closed unit disc.
In fact the above inequity is motivated by the inequality from Melas and Rubinstein [2] who proved that
if $P(z) $ is a polynomial of degree $n$ then for  $\theta \in [0, 2\pi],$
\begin{align*}
  &\int_{0}^{2\pi}\left|nP(e^{i\theta})+(1-e^{i\theta})P'(e^{i\theta})\right|^{p}d\theta\\
  &\qquad\qquad\quad \leq n^{p}\int_{0}^{2\pi}|P(e^{i\theta})|^{p}d\theta.
  \end{align*}
Alternatively the above result [due to Melas] can be established directly through an inequality due to Arestov [1] involving admissible operators on the class of polynomials.  Is my above claim right? Your suggestions are of great help.

**References**

[1] Vitaliĭ Vladimirovich Arestov, "[On integral inequalities for trigonometric polynomials and their derivatives](https://doi.org/10.1070/IM1982v018n01ABEH001375)" (Russian original)
(English translation) Mathematics of the USSR, Izvestiya 18, 1-17 (1982),  [Zbl 0517.42001](https://zbmath.org/0517.42001); Izvestiya Akademii Nauk SSSR. Seriya Matematicheskaya, 45, 3-22 (1981), [MR607574](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=607574), [Zbl 0538.42001](https://zbmath.org/0538.42001).

[2] Antonios D. Melas and Zalman Rubinstein, "[Problem 10255 and solution](https://doi.org/10.1080/00029890.1996.12004751)" American Mathematical Monthly, 103, 177-181 (1996).

Comment: The result is for polynomial of degree $n.$ I wonder if $a_n\neq 0$ can be dropped!

Comment: I have added details on why the condition $a_n\ne0$ can be dropped. In other words, I gave a counterexample with $a_n\ne0$. Do you have a further response to this?

Comment: Agreed. So nicely done! Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand\ep\varepsilon$This inequality does not hold in general.

Indeed, by continuity/denseness, the condition $a_n\ne0$ can be dropped (in response to a comment by the OP, details on this are now given at the end of this answer).

Now just take $p=2$, $\eta=-1$, $n=2$, $P(z)=1-z+0z^2$ (so that $a_0=1$ and $a_n=a_2=0$). Then the left- and right-hand sides of the conjectured inequality are $8\pi$ and $4\pi$, respectively. $\quad\Box$

---

**Details on the mentioned continuity/denseness:** Let again $p=2$, $\eta=-1$, $n=2$, but now $P(z)=1-\ep-z+\ep z^2$ with $\ep<0$ -- so that $a_0=1-\ep$ and $a_n=a_2=\ep\ne0$). Then the roots $1$ and $1/\ep-1$ of $P(z)$ are outside the open unit disk, so that $P(z)\ne0$ if $|z|<1$. Moreover, with $\ep\uparrow0$, the left- and right-hand sides of the conjectured inequality will converge to $8\pi$ and $4\pi$, respectively. More specifically, the difference between the left- and right-hand sides of the conjectured inequality will then be $4(1-\ep)\pi\to4\pi>0$.
$\quad\Box$